# Debian/Ubuntu - How to restore /var/cache/apt structure after deleting it?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, package-management

I was running out of space on an Ubuntu server, so I did this command to save space

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives
```

However now when trying to do things with apt, I get the following errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (2 No such file or directory)

E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

And things like

```
Archive directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing.
```

Clearly I have removed some directory structure. Is there some way to do a `apt-get rebuild-var-tree` or similar?

Comment: not a 'proper' answer so it'll need to be a comment but next time you could try apt-get autoclean (or possibly apt-get clean)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need two things there:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
sudo touch /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo chmod 640 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Removing this directory manually is a bad idea generally. To clean archives cleanly, use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: Under debian, I think we should not use sudo. simply use: mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
touch /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
chmod 640 /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

Comment: You should always use sudo.

Comment: In Buster, apt can set up its own directory structure if you just create the root directory: `sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt`.

Answer (score 2):

For fresh APT versions, full solution looks like:

```
sudo mkdir -m 0700 /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
sudo chown _apt:root /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```