# Debian/Ubuntu is it possible to reinitialize /var/lib/apt/lists and /var/apt/cache after deleting them?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, cache, var

Is it possible to restore the functionality of /var/lib/apt/lists and /var/apt/cache after deleting them or minmizing them in some wa

I am trying to shrink down an Ubuntu VM to the smallest size and decided to delete /var/lib/apt/lists and /var/cache/apt with the intention of restoring them when the system needs to be updated. I have done /var/cache/apt without major side effects, simply recreating some directories reenables it. The /var/lib/apt/lists is the one I am unsure of. Is it possible delete it and restore its functionality by recreating like /var/cache/apt?

Does doing that destroy the knowledge apt and dpkg have of the systems configuration or is that stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes, you can delete them!

Let's clone a VM and see what happens! :)

```
$ rm -r /var/cache/apt /var/lib/apt/lists
$ apt-get update #takes a while re-fetching everything
$ apt-get install <some-random-package>
```

Directories are recreated from the `apt-get update` operation and all is well. I might leave the `*.gpg` files alone if you're feeling paranoid, but otherwise those files are all ok to disappear.

In the past, I've had issues where I've had to manually `mkdir /var/cache/apt/archives`, but that no longer seems to be an issue.

Comment: To delete the cache, you don't need to delete the directories, just the files:
  rm -r /var/cache/apt/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: Why is the "lists" stuff not in /var/cache if it's really a cache ?
I would be reluctant to delete something that's not clearly a cache.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 10.04 LTS the directories are not recreated. So you have to be careful not to delete these.
You can use the following command to delete only the files.

```
sudo find /var/cache/apt/ -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
sudo find /var/lib/apt/lists -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

To recreate the cache use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

A better answer is probably [Debian/Ubuntu - How to restore /var/cache/apt structure after deleting it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/109970/debian-ubuntu-how-to-restore-var-cache-apt-structure-after-deleting-it?rq=1)

Comment: Or you can just add trailing forward slashes.... "rm -r /var/cache/apt/*"